# Airbnb Rendr RESTful API authentication

Tags: rest, authentication, rendr

I've been playing around with [AirBnb's Rendr](https://github.com/airbnb/rendr) using the [app template](https://github.com/airbnb/rendr-app-template) they provided on GitHub.

In their example they connect to a RESTful API using HTTP Basic Auth. However in their code they provide the credentials for authentication directly on server startup like so:

```
$ BASIC_AUTH=githubusername:githubpassword grunt server
```

Now I'm asking myself if and how I can make this more dynamic, i.e. using the credentials a user has provided on the login of my client application or even use a different authentication schema, like OAuth for example?

Is this possible? Can someone provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the app template as described you first have to implement session management [look at this example](https://github.com/airbnb/rendr-app-template/pull/27) and customize the authentication schema (basic auth) used to interact with the restful-api provided in the data-adapter file.

```
rendr-app-template/server/lib/data_adapter.js.

basicAuth = process.env.BASIC_AUTH;
if (basicAuth != null) {
authParts = basicAuth.split(':');
 api.auth = {
   username: authParts[0],
   password: authParts[1],
   sendImmediately: true
 };
}
```